# Extracting subfigure from plots to plot another figure and assigning variable to axes labels in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a code which goes like this:

```
clear; close all; clc;
SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine = 1.5;
SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont = 12;

%% 1st figure
x1 = 1:0.01:2;
y1 = 10:0.1:20;
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) % For full screen
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(x1,y1,'LineWidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)
set(gca,'linewidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)% Changes width of the axes
xlabel('x values');
ylabel('y values');
legend({'Y1 Values'},'FontSize',SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont)
title('Plot # 1')
ax = gca;
ax.FontSize = SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont;
ax.YScale = 'log';

%% 2nd figure
x2 = 2:0.01:3;
y2 = 20:0.1:30;
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(x2,y2,'LineWidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)
set(gca,'linewidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)% Changes width of the axes
xlabel('x values');
ylabel('y values');
legend({'Y2 Values'},'FontSize',SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont)
title('Plot # 2')
ax = gca;
ax.FontSize = SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont;
ax.YScale = 'log';

%% 3rd figure
x3 = 3:0.01:4;
y3 = 30:0.1:40;
subplot(3,1,3)
p3 = plot(x3,y3,'LineWidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine);
set(gca,'linewidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)% Changes width of the axes
xlabel('x values');
ylabel('y values');
legend({'Y3 Values'},'FontSize',SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont)
title('Plot # 3')
ax = gca;
ax.FontSize = SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont;
ax.YScale = 'log';
% print('-dpng','Figure1');

%% 4th figure
x4 = 10:0.01:20;
y4 = 100:0.1:200;
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) % For full screen
subplot(3,1,1)
p4 = plot(x4,y4,'LineWidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine);
set(gca,'linewidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)% Changes width of the axes
xlabel('x values');
ylabel('y values');
legend({'Y4 Values'},'FontSize',SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont)
title('Plot # 4')
ax = gca;
ax.FontSize = SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont;
ax.YScale = 'log';

%% 5th figure
x5 = 20:0.01:30;
y5 = 200:0.1:300;
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(x5,y5,'LineWidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)
set(gca,'linewidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)% Changes width of the axes
xlabel('x values');
ylabel('y values');
legend({'Y5 Values'},'FontSize',SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont)
title('Plot # 5')
ax = gca;
ax.FontSize = SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont;
ax.YScale = 'log';

%% 6th figure
x6 = 20:0.01:30;
y6 = 200:0.1:300;
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(x6,y6,'LineWidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)
set(gca,'linewidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)% Changes width of the axes
xlabel('x values');
ylabel('y values');
legend({'Y6 Values'},'FontSize',SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont)
title('Plot # 6')
ax = gca;
ax.FontSize = SizeOfAxesAndLegendFont;
ax.YScale = 'log';
% print('-dpng','Figure2');
```

This produce 2 figures which are as shown:
[image: Fig1]
[image: Fig2]

1. Now I want to create another figure (3rd one) taking plot # 3 and plot # 4 and putting together. How can this be accomplished? I was expecting that I can assign variables to individual subplots including the axes (say p3 and p4) and use the command something like this:

   ```
   figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) % For full screen
   subplot(2,1,1)
   p3
   subplot(2,1,2)
   p4
   ```
2. One can see I am suing `ylabel('y values');` six times. Is it possible that one can assign a variable (say `ylab`) to it and then use it wherever I want?

I am using Matlab 2016a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the second part - yes, easily. Just assign the string to a variable:

```
yLable = 'y values';
```

And the write:

```
ylabel(yLable);
```

---

As for the first question, you could go like this:

```
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) % For full screen
ax = subplot(2,1,1);
copyobj(p3,ax)
ax = subplot(2,1,2);
copyobj(p4,ax)
```

Here, you get the handle of the subplot (in `ax`) and copy into it the lines with their chosen handle (`p3,p4`), using the `copyobj` function.

However, this will not copy the whole axes (with labels and so on...), but only the line. If you want to copy the axes you need to go one step higher in the hierarchy and give your figure a handle (`f3` below). Also you will need to get the axes handle in the following lines in your code:

```
...
ax3 = subplot(3,1,3) %<-note the assignment
p3=plot(x3,y3,'LineWidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)
...
ax4 = subplot(3,1,1) %<-note the assignment
p4=plot(x4,y4,'LineWidth',SizeOfAxesAndPlotLine)
...
```

Then copy the axes into the figure:

```
f3 = figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) % For full screen
copyobj(ax3,f3);
copyobj(ax4,f3);
```

This will retain every property of the axes, including its position in the figure, which probably not needed here (since you call `subplot` with different arguments). To deal with that we can create empty axes with `subplot`, grab its position, assign the position to the copied axes and delete it. We do that for each axes copied:

```
f3 = figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) % For full screen
axPos = subplot(2,1,1); % dummy axes 1
ax = copyobj(ax3,f3);
ax.Position = axPos.Position; % set the position to dummy axes 1
delete(axPos) % delete dummy axes 1

axPos = subplot(2,1,2); %<-dummy axes 2
ax = copyobj(ax4,f3);
ax.Position = axPos.Position; % set the position to dummy axes 2
delete(axPos) % delete dummy axes 2
```

And we get:

[image: plots 3 and 4]

Comment: Yes, this is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. However some questions:
1) The legends are not coming in the final plot. What to do if we have to that also?
2) In the modified command, if we assign another plot using subplot(3,1,3), the axes are ovelapping each other. How can we rectify this?
3) Is it necessary that we should have handle like p3, p4? I do not see it is being used any where!

Comment: 1) You right, legends are not copied because they are considered different axes. 2)`subplot` do to take into account what's already in the figure. You should complete the planning of the division of the figure before copying the axes (with dummy axes or hardcoded values), and then copy the axes to them. 3) No. I did not delete them to minimize the changes to your code but for this purpose, you only need `ax3` and `ax4`.

Comment: in continuing to (1) I forgot to mention that I think the simplest way to have also the legend is to recreate it.